# Does today's date intersect existing ranges in database PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm creating a time off requester for my business and I think I've run into a small issue.

Goal:
I want to display a page that will show me if anyone has request the current day off.

Problem:
I have the date_from and date_to fields which contain the information of the start and end dates for each request off. However, and I apologize if I'm just over thinking (under thinking?) the solution, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to compare if today's current date (yyyy-mm-dd) intersects with any of the current records in my database. I've tried toying around with the between query but haven't had much luck.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TheTable
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
```

Comment: Thank you much.   so close!  Now it all seems clear!  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! So try it out and let us know if it's doing exactly what you want (there are many possible glitches: timezone on the DB server vs the client, do you want the bounds included or not, &c, and each such glitch can be solved if you do meet it and explain the resulting problem precisely).

Comment: This seems to work just great.   Currently I don't need to do anything with times just dates so thankfully this is a quick and easy solution!